# Wifi connection fail

Tags: networking, wireless, vmware, connection

I have VmWare installed in my laptop's Windows10 environment and Ubuntu installed in my VmWare workstation. I am connected to the wifi connection provided by my school through the Windows but when I turn on the Ubuntu in the VmWare application, the wifi does not exist and I do not have the wifi connection. I tried many ways, but I was not able to connect my Ubuntu to the wifi hot-spot. It is to say that I do not know the hot-spot's ip address, MAC address and other specification. I only know the name of the wifi and its password. Also, I am able to connect my home wifi (automatically) into the Ubuntu. Please help me set the wifi connection up automatically into Ubuntu installed in my laptop.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? This will help in troubleshooting and resolving your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you run Ubuntu in a virtual environment you do not setup any internet settings in Ubuntu unless you are using a usb wifi adapter, in other words if windows is connected to the internet you should have internet working automatically in Ubuntu in the virtual enviroment.

I use virtualbox and I do not have to change any settings to get the internet to work when I am setting up the install, it just works but even if windows is connected by wifi, in the virtual enviroment the icon in the top panel shows an ethernet connection.

Including a screenshot of my internet settings from when I installed Ubuntu in virtualbox.
[image]

Have you opened a browser to see if it connects?

To be clear when you run an operating system in a virtual environment it does not see your physical hardware that is why if you have an internet connection in windows the host system you should have an internet connection in the virtual enviroment which is the guest system if the settings are correct when you installed Ubuntu, if not you can change the settings while the virtual environment is turned off.